# Как заставить работать distinct() с order_by('?')?

Tags: python, django

Долго возился с distinct() недоумевая, почему он не работает. Потом решил от балды поменять order_by('?') на order_by('name') и на удивление заработало.

Возможно distinct() при случайной сортировке не понимает что сравнивать, я не в курсе его принципа действия, но хотелось бы каким-то образом заставить его работать.

Возможно есть замена случайной сортировке через order_by('?') и чтобы это хорошо работало с distinct().

В общем, нужна помощь. Помогите пожалуйста.

А, чуть не забыл. БД - SQLite, сам сайт на Django.

Comment: Оператор `DISTINCT` в SQL **требует** сортировки. Поэтому совместить у вас не выйдет.

Comment: Тогда попробую как-нибудь провернуть аналог случайной сортировки.
За информацию спасибо.

Comment: А зачем вам здесь вообще distinct? У вас что ли бывают один-в-один несколько копий одной и той же Article?

Comment: Да. Создавал что-то по типу "другие записи из категории". Если у статьи категорий несколько, то каждая может выдать одну и ту же статью. Если бы дублей не было, то я бы и не ставил distinct().

Answer (score 0):

Ну что ж, если distinct() не хочет дружиться с order_by('?'), то order_by сам подружится с distinct().

Сделал какого-то рода костыль случайной сортировке, ну или просто замену.

```
def random():
    a = ['', '-']
    b = ['id', 'date', 'name', 'author', 'slug', 'views']
    c = a[randint(0, 1)] + b[randint(0, 5)]
    return c

context = {
    'rand_list': Article.objects.order_by(random()).distinct()[:10]
}
```

Если у кого есть какие-то предложения или критика ( что может быть проще ее :D ) - пишите. Будет интересно узнать чье-то мнение.